# Pillow saving image blank after cropping

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

So am trying to extract image from browser, first image img.jpg saves perfectly but cropped screensho.jpg saves as blank img.

I am using PIL library for this, image is saving as 180x50 as it should but its blank.

```
image = Image.open("img.jpg")
rgb_im = image.convert('RGB')
left = location['x'] # 902
top = location['y'] # 1915
right = location['x'] + size['width'] # 902+180
bottom = location['y'] + size['height'] # 1915+50
im = rgb_im.crop((left, top, right, bottom)) # defines crop points
im.save('screenshot.jpg') # saves new cropped image
```

Could this be the "minimum limits" of pil ?

Comment: What's the variable `location` and `size`?

Comment: Location of element taken from selenium.

x=902
y=1915

Size is also taken from element and its 180 x 50

Comment: I think the number `left` is larger than the width of your image, or the top is larger than the height of your image.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium is not screening entire page by default.

To get around it i used

```
    element = driver.find_elements_by_id('idofelemtineeded')[0]
    element_png = element.screenshot_as_png
    with open("screen.png", "wb") as file:
        file.write(element_png)
```